# Nested dependencies and private repositories with composer

Tags: composer-php

At the company I'm currently working we've recently started to move our code into different private repositories so that it's more maintainable and reusable (and also to make it easier to open-source it later).

Every PHP repository is also a Composer package that can be required in our project whenever we need it.

At the moment there's an issue with this approach: every time we need a package that depends on other packages we need to specify those also in the root *composer.json*.

For example, let's say that the in the root *composer.json* we need to require two packages `company\b` and `company\c`, and that the package `company\c` needs another package `company\d`. Then the resulting root `composer.json` will look like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "company/b": "dev-master",
        "company/c": "dev-master",
        "company/d": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\" : "src\Company"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:company/b.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:company/c.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:company/d.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying nested dependencies in the root *composer.json* and use the ones specified in the *composer.json* in every package?

**Edit**:
Everything I stated before is valid only for the private packages. If a package, let's say `company\b`, needs a public package that can be found on Packagist then that dependency CAN be specified in the `company\b` *composer.json* and it will be imported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you correctly found out, only the root package can add repository metadata to the collection of known packages.

I would suggest you take a look at [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) to create a local Composer repository. This would only require you to add this single repository to all your `composer.json` files of all packages, and it will be used as an updatable source of knowledge about all your private repositories. You no longer have to add a list of Git repos everywhere.

I am successfully hosting around 120 internal packages for our IT enterprise that way. Take this as a sign that once you start splitting isolated tasks into a package, you will get more of them pretty fast.

Also note that it is important to take versioning seriously. Stop depending on branches - tag your software, make releases, use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org). If you don't, things will break at some point, and people will curse you (correct) or Composer (incorrect) for not working or messing things up.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct for the additional infos. Luckily we're already using versioning internally so will definitely give Satis a try.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search and a look at the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) I discovered that the `repositories` can only be specified in the root *composer.json*.

Additionally it's possible to specify in the root *composer.json* whether to allow or not development versions of the packages using:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

Also [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2632) on GitHub was really useful.